# What penalty does a medium load apply to a characters Jump skill?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, encumbrance, pcgen

PCGen is telling me that my PC with a Medium Load suffers a −9 to jump in the "Misc Mod" column. The other DEX based skills have a −3.

If I remove the load in PCGen, it completely removes the −9.

I know Swin applies ×2 to the penalty; but I'm aware of no such multiplication with Jump and can't find anything in the SRD to support this.

Software bug, or have a missed something?

Comment: It may be of interest to you: Jump skill is STR (not DEX) based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jump is penalized when your movement speed is below 30 ft. A medium load reduces your speed to 20 ft so you take a −6 penalty for that. It also has an armor check penalty of −3, so you end up with −9.